# Confusion about TimeoutException in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, timeout, future

I use the following toy-code to test the `TimeoutException` in Scala:

```
import java.util.concurrent._

object TestTime {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("starting....")
    val service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor
    try {
      val r = new Runnable() {
        override def run(): Unit = {
          //your task
          val t0 = System.nanoTime: Double
          println(s"1+...+100=${sum(100)}")
          val t1 = System.nanoTime: Double
          println("Elapsed time " + (t1 - t0) / 1e6 + " mill-secs")
        }
      }

      val f = service.submit(r)
      // attempt the task for 0.2 second
      f.get(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    } catch {
      case e: TimeoutException =>
        service.shutdownNow()
        println(s"Timeout: $e")
    } finally {
      service.shutdown()
    }
  }

  //Given that sum() is written by others and I cannot change it.
  def sum(k: Int): BigInt = {
    var total: BigInt = 0
    for (i <- 1 to k) {
      total += i
    }
    total
  }
}
```

When I run the above code, the console shows `sum(100)` takes about `29 milliseconds`. However, the code throwS the `TimeoutException`(because `29 < 200`, the code should not have `TimeoutException`).

[image]

When I change `f.get(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` to `f.get(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`. This time `sum` takes `27 milliseconds`, it exceeds the threshold `20`. However, the code gives the result normally.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which Scala + Java version are you running?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I run it just now with `f.get(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`, I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGYq6.jpg) Normaly, the `1+...+100=5050 Elapsed time 31.542153 mill-secs` should not occur on the console because of `time-out`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Java `1.8` + Scala`2.11.8`

Comment: I ran with exactly the same setup and it doesn't throw.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Which version of scala/java do you used?

Comment: Scala: 2.11.8, Java 1.8.0_121

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Could you give me a screenshot when you run the above code with `f.get(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)` and `f.get(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`? Thanks very much.

Comment: 200 Milliseconds: http://imgur.com/a/N6LsD, 20 Milliseconds: http://imgur.com/a/vpjk5

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov For the 20 case, your screenshot shows `16 <20`, so the TimeoutException should not ocucr.

Comment: That's a race condition, 20 milliseconds is too sensitive. It might take 4 milliseconds for the runtime to print your string to STDOUT, and that might cause the thread to run longer, so it isn't actually 16ms, it's more.